# How to parse a binary 64-bit double timestamp in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, double, buffer, binary-data

I am working with binary data that is passed btween two diffrent envrionments (Node and Python)
On the first end a stimestamp is packed using python strcut library as a 8-byte double as shown bellow:

```py
timeStamp = struct.pack("<d", int(time.time()))
```

On the other end, i have a node.js server that is supposse to receive this binary data and parse it back to decimal. I am having trouble parseing this value back in node.js using the Buffer library.

I have tried the following with the Node.js Buffer library.

```
let read_pos = 0;
 const raw_data = Buffer.from(bin_data, 'binary'); 
 const int_time_stamp = raw_data.readDoubleLE(read_pos);
 read_pos += 8;
```

The above code executes just fine but the output that I get is not a value that can represent a timestamp in seconds since the Epoch. For example I get a decimal number like 3.50006400573813e while I am expecting something like 1695077817. It is worth mentioning that other pieces of data that are part of the binary message (1 byte integers for example) are parsed correctly.

Comment: What is the value of `bin_data` in your node.js script? I've made the assumption that it is a hex string value and so the following modification works for me `const raw_data = Buffer.from('0000002fa142d941ffffffffff', 'hex'); 
`

Comment: @ukBaz, the data is in binary format not hex. `Buffer.from(bin_data, 'binary');`  returns an array of bytes.

Comment: How is the data sent from the python environment tot he node.js environment. The time stamp is about the value `1695077817` that is generated in python and converted to bytes. But what is the value when it turns up in `bin_data`?  Your conversion steps look about right. So is it going wrong before it gets to this stage?